# R Key Press without Blocking / Event Handling

Tags: r, events, keyboard, event-handling

I am having difficulty finding a solution for my R code to check the status of a key press without blocking execution. This is for some very simple demo "animation".

I am on RStudio 1.0.136, Mac OS X 10.13.3, R 3.3.3.

I have tried the "keypress" library from Cran but keypress_support() returns false and

```
key<-keypress(block = FALSE)
```

returns an error

> "Your platform/terminal does not support keypress".

I have tried using events in an x11 graphics window but clearly I am misunderstanding something, as the idle function never gets called when I use getGraphicsEvent():

```
#Please ignore the nasty global varables, quick eample!
# When q is pressed return non-null to exit
keydown <- function(key) {
  if (key == "q") return(invisible(1))
  NULL
}

#Plots a new blob in the idle state!
pants <- function() {
  points(x[i], y[i], pch = 19, cex = 2,col="red")
  i<<-i+1
  NULL
}

#Start here
x11(width = 10, height = 3)

n = 2000
x = sort(rnorm(n))
y = rnorm(n)
i=0

plot.new()
plot.window(c(1, n), c(0, 1))

setGraphicsEventHandlers(prompt = "Click q to quit",
                         onMouseDown = NULL,
                         onMouseUp = NULL,
                         onIdle=pants,
                         onKeybd = keydown)

eventEnv <- getGraphicsEventEnv()

plot(x, y, type = "n")

# I assumed this would continue to call the idle process until 
# a non-idle event is triggers, but it never gets called?
getGraphicsEvent()
print("end")
```

I am trying to devise code that plots points in a (continuous) loop and when a keyboard event is detected calls a function to respond.

Comment: The [kepress README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keypress/README.html) says this will only work with R from the terminal (it will not work with RStudio or any other GUI). The R language is just not designed to handle user interrupts from loops like this. Maybe you can look at using something like shiny that implements an event loop for R. But still, you'd have to work with intervals that update state rather than endless loops.

Comment: Thank you. I understand I am trying to use R for something it was not designed for - but it would be useful as a demonstration for a simple on screen demo of reinforcement learning. I was hoping the x11 interface might provide an “event” method and it looks like it almost does!

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/coolbutuseless/eventloop by any chance? (Only works on Ubuntu & Mac apparently though, not on Windows)